# What are raw cells in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I know code, I understood markdown.

I have read [this Raw cells article](https://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/0.2.3/raw-cells.html), but could not make out much.

And what is esoteric **NBConvert**?

Please throw some light.

[image]

Comment: Probably raw text

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The updated docs at https://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.1/raw-cells.html explain it pretty well.

Basically it's only of any use if you intend to use the command line tool `nbconvert` to convert the notebook to another format (such as HTML or Latex). When you do, cells marked as Raw NBConvert Format will be converted in a way specific to the output you're targetting.